# How to use dotenv without having to require it in each file?

Tags: node.js

Every tutorial states that we need to require the `dotenv` package in each node file. However a youtube video state that we can create a file at `bin/dev` and add this

```
require('dotenv/config')
require('./../server.js')
```

According to the video all the variables at `.env` would be accessible to all the files.

I can't get it working, is there a way to do this or is it deprecated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To not require dotenv everywhere, you could preload it using --require (-r) while starting your script:

```
node -r dotenv/config your_script.js
```

Also, if you need to pass parameters, it could be like:

```
node -r dotenv/config your_script.js dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/your/env/vars
```